# How to do a Foreach loop or Each within Azure Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-yaml-pipelines

I am trying to run an Azure Pipeline that queries an Azure Storage table, I can do this no problem by passing in $AppName from a normal pipeline variable, but id like to loop though multiple apps from an app list within the yaml file.

The yaml file I am using is below:

```
trigger:
  - master

variables:
  - name: AppNames
    value:
      [
        "7zip",
        "AdobeAcrobatReaderDC",
        "CitrixWorkspaceApp",
        "GoogleChrome",
        "LAPS",
        "Mimecast",
        "Nessus",
        "NotepadPlusPlus",
        "MicrosoftWvdRemoteDesktop",
      ]
  - name: baseurl
    value: $(NexusProdRepo)
  - name: genRepo
    value: $(ClientRepo)
  - name: APIKey
    value: $(PRODAPIKey)

pool:
  name: $(PoolName)
  demands:
    - agentOS -equals $(agentOS)

stages:
  - stage: Deployment
    jobs:
      - job: DeployApps
        steps:
          - script: echo "Deploying $(AppName)"
            env:
              AppName: ${{ each.value }}
        forEach: ${{ variables.AppNames }}
      - stage: QueryAzureTableStorage_Stage
        dependsOn:
          - ConnectiontoAzure
        jobs:
          - job: QueryAzureTableStorage_Job
            steps:
              - task: PowerShell@2
                displayName: "Query Azure Table Storage"
                name: "Query_Azure_Table_Storage"
                inputs:
                  targetType: filePath
                  filePath: "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/GetAndQueryStorageTable.ps1"
                  arguments: "-StorageAccountName $(StorageAccountName) -ResourceGroupName $(ResourceGroupName) -TableName $(TableName) -AppName $(AppName)"
```

Is anyone able to correct me on where I'm going wrong regards the foreach loop, or if its even possible?

Answer (score 1):

> loop though multiple apps from an app list within the yaml file.

Based on your requirement, I suggest that you can use Parameters and Each expression in YAML Pipeline.  Refer to this doc: [Each keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#each-keyword)

Here is an example:

```
parameters:
- name: AppNames
  type: object
  default: [7zip,AdobeAcrobatReaderDC]
  


stages:
  - ${{ each app in parameters.AppNames  }}:
    - stage: Deployment_${{ app }}
      jobs:
        - job: DeployApps
          steps:
            - script: echo "Deploying "${{ app }}""
```

**Result:**

[image]